# How to get client unique ID in JavaScript but it should be same if we remove the cookie of browser

Tags: javascript, uniqueidentifier

i need unique ID of client by JavaScript. Also i have used fingerprint for the same but it is not working, it is return duplicate ids so please help how to resolve it...

Comment: I don't think there's any completely reliable method. Cookies are best, you just have to live with the fact that users can delete cookies.

Comment: You **should not** rely on sensitive data coming from client

Comment: Thanks for reply, our application fully depend on client unique ID because we want to track user activity. please suggest it critical for us.